# YotubePlayer custom controllers

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to make custom controllers for player. In portrait orientation I place player in FrameLayout, set up `player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS)` and place custom views on player view (using padding, etc). But how I can do this in FullScreenMode?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/yvPlayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_id"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/video_play_btn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/play_circle"
            tools:background="@drawable/play_circle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_information"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/yvPlayer"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_current_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="00:01"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color" />

            <org.adw.library.widgets.discreteseekbar.DiscreteSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/video_seekBar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:dsb_indicatorColor="@color/pink_color"
                app:dsb_min="1"
                app:dsb_progressColor="@color/pink_color"
                app:dsb_rippleColor="@color/pink_color"
                app:dsb_trackColor="@color/grey_transparent_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_length"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="99:99"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/video_fullscreen"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/fullscreen" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>               

<include
    android:id="@+id/video_bar"
    layout="@layout/transparent_layout" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh1sm.png)

Comment: just set setFullscreen(boolean fullscreen). after setting the player style

Comment: @Android when i set CHROMLESS style there are no default controls in fullscreen mode and my custom controls absent to

Comment: yeah there will no any default control , you have to create your own.please show your piece of code which you tried.

Comment: @d.datul1990 Hi. No. As I know YouTubePlayer doesn't allow to place another views over it. So i decided to use default controls

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Android's answer.

Yes it is correct. Use  ['*YoutubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener - setFullscreen(boolean)*'](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener) this is to inform the player that it is being laid out full screen. Calling this function may affect the looks of the player's control, changing the layout to better suit the current player size.

Calling 'YoutubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener' will fire '**onFullscreen()** event.